# Basic Spring 4 Websocket application

Tags: spring, websocket, spring-4, spring-websocket

I'm attempting to build a basic Hello World Spring websockets app however I can't seem to hit the WebSocket endpoint, what am I missing?

I have added the `TextWebSocketHandler`, `WebSocketConfigurer`, and also have a `AbstractContextLoaderInitializer` which initialises a `AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext` that scans the package that contain my websocket classes.

The websocket is called like so: `ws://localhost:8080/client/websocket`

Is there missing configuration? I don't want to use STOMP or socksjs. There is no other configuration in the app, perhaps further Spring config is required?

Comment: Did you manage to make it work? If so then how?

Answer (score 0):

Is your Configuration annotated with the `@EnableWebSocket` annotation?
Do you register your WebSockethandler on the correct path?

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketServerConfiguration implements WebSocketConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    protected MyWebSocketHandler webSocketHandler;

    @Override
    public void registerWebSocketHandlers(WebSocketHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addHandler(webSocketHandler, "/as");
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, all is good. The only difference to the code above is that I haven't Autowire, I manually create the Handler instance: registry.addHandler(new WebSocketHandler(), "/as");

Comment: maybe your package doesn't get scanned? try to log something in your constructor of the Configuration-File, to see if it gets initialized, when spring starts.